nested safes with @safe-global/protocol-kit?
How to use the sdk for signing and transacting with nested safes? Below is the way I work with single layer. But let's say that safeAddress is the 1/1 to another safe: nestedSafeAddress.
const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({
  ethers,
  signerOrProvider: signer,
});

const safeSdk = await Safe.create({
  ethAdapter: ethAdapter,
  safeAddress: safeAddress
});


You can follow examples to interact with a nested safe here. Also, please note that since v4 of the SDK, it is no longer necessary to use EthersAdapters to instanciate the kit.
Hope it helps; Best, Louis
